# how to access original value of the variable

Tags: java

Let's say I have this code

```
public static long number;
public static void main(String args[]) {
    String str1 = args[0];
    System.out.println("str1 is = " + str1);
    long number = Long.parseLong(str1);
    System.out.println("number value is = " + number);
}

public static void test1(){
    System.out.println("number value inside test1 is = " + number);
}
```

Say I pass 12345 as argument, so my o/p will be

```
 str1 is  12345
 number value is  12345
 number value inside test1 is  0
```

What I want is to be able to access arg[0] (user argument) or original value of number (12345) inside test1 method as well. Pls help me do it. Thanks.!

Comment: `test1` could be a method if it only had brackets: `test1()`...

Answer (score 3):

Set your class-level `number` to the parsed value of `str1`.  Currently, you set a local field which has no scope beyond the main method.

Use:

```
number = Long.parseLong(str1);
```

instead of:

```
long number = Long.parseLong(str1);
```

Comment: @user1629109 - Vulcan is correct.  When you said `long number = Long.parseLong(str1);` inside main(), you created a *NEW, DIFFERENT* "number", so your global "number" never got assigned.

Answer (score 0):

For that you would either need to use global variables or you would need to pass the value to `test1` function.

You tried to use global variables, but you don't need to have the type in front of it when you initialize it, because then it becomes local.  So just use:

```
number = Long.parseLong(str1);
```

Here is your code when it passes the value to `test1`:

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
    String str1 = args[0];
    System.out.println("str1 is = "+str1);
    long number = Long.parseLong(str1);
    System.out.println("number value is = "+number);
}

public static void test1(long number){
     System.out.println("number value inside test1 is = "+number);
}
```

Then you'll just have to use

```
test1(number);
```

somewhere inside your `main()` method.

Answer (score 0):

`long number = Long.parseLong(str1);`

Doing the above you are **Declaring another variable named** `number`.

Do this to access the `Class variable` (ie. static field)

`number = Long.parseLong(str1);`